# Android(Mobile) vision camera brightness is very low

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-vision

I have integrated google vision in my project as shown in below post:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

Everything looks fine except the camera view brightness . The camera view here is very dark when comparing with my actual android camera app.

Please let me know if i can increase the brightness of the camera and turn on any low light settings. Thanks .

Pictures : 
[Camera picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHqIL.png)
,
[App Camera view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOSEX.png)

Comment: have you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Adding `.setRequestedFps(15.0f)` while Building CameraSource resolved my problem.
Seems like the fps count has something to do with brightness.
My builder looks like that:

```
CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getActivity(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used xzing later for barcode scanning. But this is good information.

Comment: I've tried zxing too, but for me google vision is better. It's just easier to implement and you can scan barcodes in any orientation :)

Comment: This works brother, can you help how to set  exposure parameters to auto adjust the brightness depend on devices?