# Accessing the Camera from com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource and Increasing/Decreasing the Preview Brightness

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview, vision-api

I Have to implement in Google Vision API's CameraSource for build the camera and do the face detection on before capturing the image. Now I have faced few issues, So I need to access the camera object from CameraSource.

1. How could I achieve the increase or Decrease the Camera Preview Brightness using CameraSource?

This is my CameraSource Builder

```
 mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
                .build();
```

Here I have to try to access/get the camera from mCameraSource object.

```
Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    Camera camera = (Camera) field.get(mCameraSource);
                    if (camera != null) {
                        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();                        
                        params.setExposureCompensation(1500);
                        camera.setParameters(params);
                    }
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

but the `camera` returns null only, And My 2nd Question is how to do brightness option...

```
if (camera != null) {
     Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();                        
     params.setExposureCompensation(1500);
     camera.setParameters(params);
 }
```

Comment: this post will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147675/androidmobile-vision-camera-brightness-is-very-low

Comment: try this too https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/162

Comment: @NishantBijaniA, Both are I tried but no improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to achieve my target like this,

Camera Brightness level is -12 to 12. So minimum brightness level is -12, the Maximum brightness level is 12.

now I have to Customize the CameraSourcePreview constructor like

```
private int defaultBrightness = 12;

public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mStartRequested = false;
    mSurfaceAvailable = false;

    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
    addView(mSurfaceView);
    mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraFocus(mCameraSource, brightness);
        }
    });
}

private static boolean cameraFocus(@NonNull CameraSource cameraSource, int brightness) {
    Field[] declaredFields = CameraSource.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if (field.getType() == Camera.class) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Camera camera = (Camera) field.get(cameraSource);
                if (camera != null) {
                    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                        params.setExposureCompensation(brightness);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then I have to implement the dynamic brightness adjustment through the seekbar.

like

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {


                cameraFocus(mCameraSource,i-12);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });
```

seekbar xml code

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="24"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

finally, I got the solution... :)

Comment: How you are adding seekbar to CameraSourcePreview.

Comment: How did that solve the problem with camera always is null?

Comment: I found the reason was the cameraSource.start(*) was not called - only after it is called it will be possible to get the field value. https://gist.github.com/Gericop/7de0b9fdd7a444e53b5a

Comment: But when I try to set the parameters value I get this error: `Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(java.lang.String)`